# What happens when you run ng serve?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've been using [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) for the last little while. It comes with a number of commands including `ng serve` which spins up a server at `localhost:4200`.

I'm used to using Grunt and Gulp which can be configured to suit my needs. I wanted to configure Angular-CLI's server but then I realized I didn't know what it was or how to configure it. Grepping the project for `serve` hasn't unearthed anything that seems useful.

So, what exactly does `ng serve` do?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Nowadays, it uses `webpack-dev-server` to start a local webserver. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686176/what-server-does-ng-serve-use-when-using-angular-cli-1-6-0).

From the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/afbddfe348e532c48d272cf9b4273b9ef7af06c7/docs/documentation/stories/disk-serve.md):

> The CLI supports running a live browser reload experience to users by running ng serve. This will compile the application upon file saves and reload the browser with the newly compiled application. This is done by hosting the application in memory and serving it via [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#webpack-dev-server).

---

**Original answer:**

After some research here's what I've gathered.

Angular-CLI piggybacks certain things off of Ember CLI. It would appear that `ng serve` is one of those things. Ember has an `ember server` command which is defined in [this file](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/lib/commands/serve.js) and seems to match the behavior of `ng serve`.

Comment: One thing I cannot figure out is which folder is being served to the browser  with ng-serve. I thought it would be running ng-build (ie, output to the outdir folder in the config) and serving that, however you can erase that folder while http://localhost:4200/ is running and it has no effect. So where is it compiling all of the bundles to? UPDATE:  Here is the answer - in memory:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087369/where-does-ng-serve-output-files-to

Comment: I wonder how much this answer still applies now that Angular CLI uses Webpack.