# Angular - ng serve vs npm start

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have a little question about angular-cli.

Is it true that when I run **ng serve** I use the **global** installed angular-cli and when I run **npm start** the **local** one?

Comment: Where are you getting this information? I am inclined to believe this is false. When I run `npm start` on my cli project, it just runs `ng serve`.

Comment: I asked this question because i have globally installed angular-cli with version 1.0.0-beta.26 and locally the latest with version 1.0.0-beta.32.3.

And when i run ng serve i'm getting error, and when run npm start everything is ok

Comment: Another thing that convinces me that this is true. I have just uninstall globall angular-cli with `npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli` and now when i try run `ng serve`, it's says that ng in not recognized whereas `npm start` still works

Comment: Here's [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190538/when-to-use-npm-start-and-when-to-use-ng-serve)! you can refer to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use 'npm start' and when to use 'ng serve'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190538/when-to-use-npm-start-and-when-to-use-ng-serve)

Answer (score 5):

Command will decide by `package.json`  . ng serve / npm start is used based on `package.json` can change form there. if `ng serve` is not working can use `npm start` to run server.

**ng server :**

> `"scripts": {
>       "ng": "ng",
>       "start": "ng serve",
>       "test": "ng test",.......
>     }`

Answer (score 5):

When you run the `npm start` internally it will call whatever command is written inside the start in the `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve"
}
```

it will run the `ng serve`

For more details, check [When to use 'npm start' and when to use 'ng serve'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190538/when-to-use-npm-start-and-when-to-use-ng-serve)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is true.

Let's say your global Angular CLI version is 2 and you just cloned and installed a project from github that is created with Angular CLI version 1. If you run `ng serve` it will execute using version 2 (which is your global cli), if you run `npm run start` it will use the script in node_modules/.bin folder (which is local to your project and which is the right one for the job).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is true. **ng serve** runs the app on angular global cli on the **current version** of the installed angular version while **npm run start** runs it on the version of that **particular angular application** cloned version from the node-module.