# how can I get this angular project up and running?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, nativescript

I'm getting familiar with NativeScript and I downloaded the following Angular-based NativeScript project from play.nativescript.org:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Hqp5UQ&v=320

I opened a cmd prompt from the top-level directory that I downloaded and tried "ng serve." I don't remember the specific error but git bash instructed me to run the following cmd:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

I tried "ng serve" again but then git bash returned the following error:

> "Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found"

I googled this and found a thread on SO where someone mentioned to exec "ng update":

[Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810580/error-local-workspace-file-angular-json-could-not-be-found)

So I did an "ng update" but now git bash returns an error:

> "Error compiling schema", followed by a bunch of minified js followed
>   by a red error message at the end "Unexpected token function"

Any idea what I might be missing here?  What steps should I follow to get this up and running if I start over from scratch?

Comment: Just a note: All playground projects can be directly deployed within few seconds using this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nativescript.play&hl=bg  and then you could change the code and upon save the changes will be synced on your device

Comment: If you want to play with NativeScript locally you will need to install the prerequisites - in that case follow the instuctions in the detailed answers below

Answer (score 2):

Like the other answerer pointed out -- the Angular CLI does not encompass everything that NativeScript is designed to do. For that they have their own CLI:

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli

From my skimming of the docs above, it looks like this is the correct flow:

Install the CLI:
`npm install nativescript -g`

Create a new app:
`tns create MyApp --template angular` and then browse to the project `cd MyApp`

Add the platforms you care about:
`tns platform add android`
`tns platform add ios`

And then run your project: `tns run ios` `tns run android`

---

**For a raw Angular project**

You need to use the CLI to create a new project first.

`ng new cool-app`

This will create a new folder in your current directory with an empty Angular project. In order to use "ng serve" you first have to browse to that directory.

`cd cool-app`

Now that your are in the directory, the Angular CLI has enough context to boot your new app.

`ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

Your don't use the angular cli project. So you are not be able to use commands like `ng serve`.

You can take a look here to see how to use a cli based project. [angular cli quickstart](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

BTW. you use a project from [nativescript play tool](https://play.nativescript.org/) Wich is not actually support the cli commands (as you can see in the error there is no `angular.json`).

Either use a cli based project or configure your `package.json` to serve the current project. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40190538/) question can help you.