# I am facing Issues while running npm start cmd

Tags: angular

"npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\CHANDAN MISHRA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-01T
23_11_13_476Z-debug.log"

Comment: Make sure your `package.json` has `start` in `scripts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of npm's features is the ability to define `scripts` in `package.json`. You can read the details [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts). `npm start` runs which ever command is defined as the `start` script.

This error appears to be telling you that you have not defined the `start` script at all. An example for Angular: if you want `npm start` to serve the project via a development server, your `package.json` would look like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve"
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190538/when-to-use-npm-start-and-when-to-use-ng-serve) discusses more details of Angular and `package.json`