# Display CSV Data with Angular

Tags: angular, csv, httpclient

I am Trying to display the content of a CSV File in Angular.

To Test if it can read the .csv it I wrote following Method:

```
public readCsv(){
    this.httpClient.get('/testdata/csv/test.csv', {responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
  }
```

However if I run the Application I get following error:

> Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/testdata/csv/test.csv:
>   404 Not Found

The .csv is in this folder:
    `src > app > testdata > csv > test.csv`

The api.service.ts in which I the Method is written here: `src > app > api.service.ts`

I am running the Method in the testdata.component.ts which lays here: 
`src > api > testdata > testdata.component.ts`

with following code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.apiService.readCsv();
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why do I get a 404 Not Found Error?
How could I correctly read the file and even display it?

Comment: Mime type error perhaps? An alternative could be to have an actual endpoint that reads and returns the contents of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files outside of "assets" folder are not available by default. Save your file inside your project's "assets" folder and access it like this:

```
this.httpClient.get('assets/test.csv', {responseType: 'text'}).....
```

Otherwise you would have to make your folder available in the '"assets":' section of your angular.json file.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with what happens when you run ng serve. Your implementation its build over the assumption that ng serve will start a Web Server in your src/app directory and that is not what actually happens. What is happening ([as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137521/what-happens-when-you-run-ng-serve)) is that ng serve compiles your app and starts a local server using `webpack-dev-server`.

By default the only directory included in the build to deploy is the assets directory under src/assets. You can change that in the assets section of your project in the angular.json file.

```
{
 ...
 "project": {
   "<project-name>": {
         "architect": {
              "build": {
                "assets": [<list of paths>]
                 ...
```

[See this stackblitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-csv-data)