# How can I construct a link that goes to one of my Angular app routes?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an app running at "www.example.com", which is sitting along side some static html pages. I need to provide a 'registration' link that goes to www.example.com/guest_register. This works locally, but not on the server.

Background:

When I run locally, I can create a link to http://localhost:4200/guest?token=asdf&user=username that works fine to register a new user. Out on the server, a link to http://www.example.com/guest?token=asdf&user=username gives a 404 error....an link to http://www.example.com/#/guest?token=asdf&user=username sends me to my index.html. I tried adding the '#' on a hunch, but I'm not sure what the real difference is.

The public_html directory of the server looks like:

index.html //a static page
main.html // my actual Angular app
styles.-----.js
scripts.-----.js
runtime.----.js
polyfills.----.js
main.-----.js
3rdpartylicenses.txt
assets/

I serve up index.html for the general public, and then link into main.html as needed to log in registered users. Locally, the browser address bar switches from file://..index.html to localhost:4200 when I link into my app. On the server, the address bar reloads from www.example.com to www.example.com.

Here is my route map in app.module.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: WizardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'guest', component: GuestComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
.
.
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
.
.
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
.
.
```

Nothing too fancy. So, what is keeping me from directly appending /guest to the end of the URL while on the server, but not locally?

EDIT: It seems my app is falling back to index.html when it should be falling back to main.html (my angular app) when an unrecognized URL is requested, [according to these official docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration):

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

My .htaccess already has a few mysterious lines in it that I only understand well enough to know they work to redirect all users other than my IP to maintenance.html when maintenance.enable exists:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^MY\.IP\.ADD\.RESS
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.enable -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

How do I integrate the suggestion on the official docs into my existing .htaccess file?

Comment: The server needs to be configured. https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: @sinanspd So, I should just be able to edit .htaccess to fall back to main.html instead of index.html and my routing will start working? Is that correct? I'll need some help, since my existing .htaccess already has some mystery stuff in it to route to 'maintenance.html' if 'maintenance.enable' exists.

Answer (score 1):

I will elaborate on my comment a little bit further. When you compile your Angular project, it collapses everything into a single file, this is normally what is called a [single page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) Historically, this is very different from how the web servers were setup.

The part after the first / normally translates into a file. So in the case of

```
www.example.com/guest_register
```

An out-of-the-box server looks for guest_register.html in the www folder. In the case of single page applications, this precondition is not met. You don't have a file called guest_register.html, as a result the server responds with 404.

What angular router does is, take the original request and figure out what "page" to serve you.

In a production environment, the only entry point to you application is index.html, thus you need to explicitly tell the server to redirect any 404 to index.html (fallback is the technical term)

This is not a problem when you run it locally through

```
ng serve
```

because this command starts a local server that is [configured with this behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137521/what-happens-when-you-run-ng-serve)

The details of how to configure is laid out [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)

Copying the highlights below in case the link goes down (which seems to be happening to the angular page often lately)

Apache:

add to **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
```

RewriteRule ^ /index.html

Nginx:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

Firebase:

Add to rewrite rules

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
} ]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This helps tremendously, but my .htaccess is not empty (see my edits to the original post. I'm not certain where to add the recommended stanza, given my existing .htaccess file.

Comment: @JohnMarquez Looking at your .htaccess it looks like a backup to load a maintance(?) module. I am guessing this shouldn't interfere with you paths as they don't seem to overlap. You can just append the AngularRewrites at the end of the file (outside the ifmodule). Make sure you restart the server or apache, .htaccess is basically a config file that is loaded in at the startup. If it doesn't work, try commenting out what is there but it shouldn't be necessary